# Rest vs SOAP with regards to WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I'm not completely clear on one thing and am hoping some one here will probably answer this.

I worked on an enterprise application where we had a Java app consuming services with a WSDL interface in between and a .NET application on the other side producing the services.

I have been reading RESTful webservices where jersey API is used to route a request through a jersey servlet to an URI that eventually talks to a Java class to send the data back.

I'm not able to understand the point where diverse applications like .NET and Java can talk through a REST interface and how for this particular scenario Rest is useful.How does Rest work in this case?. for SOAP there is WSDL, what about for REST assuming a Java app is consuming from a .NET through a Restful service. Please explain how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both REST and SOAP use HTTP for communication. Requests are sent over the wire using the HTTP protocol from client to server. The server replies using the same protocol. As long as the client and the server both send information using HTTP, it doesn't matter what language the client or server are written in.

RESTful APIs may use some combination of WADL, HATEOAS, and documentation to reveal their API to clients.